# Counting number of records from two different tables and grouping them

Tags: mysql

Table 1: Student(name,*enrollment_no*,dept,college_id)
Table 2: Faculty(name,*faculty_id*,dept,college_id)

Desired o/p:
Department, No. of Student, No. of faculty in one table form

query i've been trying :

```
select 
    dept,
    count(distinct student.dept) as total, 
    count(distinct faculty.dept) as total1 
from student 
join faculty 
    on student.college_id=faculty.college_id
group by dept;
```

query is not giving any output.

after your help
query is now

```
select * from (
(select count(*)as stu_count,student.department,student.college_id 
from student group by department)T1 
inner join 
(select count(*)as fact_count,faculty_per.department,faculty_per.college_id 
from faculty_per group by department)T2 
on T1.college_id=T2.college_id);
```

Thank you.

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) 
if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and 
provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Why do you have **")** in the ON clause of your join? What's wrong with the output of your query? Edit your question and show the output of the query,and an example of what you want it to produce.

Comment: Your query should produce an error because of the **dept** in the group by. You need to specify which dept, either student.dept or faculty.dept.

Comment: Did you read the comments above? I do not see where you edited your question and added the requested info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from ((select count(*)as stu_count,t2.dept,t2.college_id from Student group by dept)T1
inner join
(select count(*)as fact_count,t3.dept,t3.college_id from Facultygroup by dept)T2
on T1.college_id=T2.college_id);
```

No of students and faculty can be extracted by performing inner join on two separate queries. Distinct is not required as we are doing group by

Comment: Sorry, I cannot get what is t3?

Comment: Remove them that is not necessary. Actually i have tables with name t2 for student and t3 for faculty

Comment: select * from ((select count(*)as stu_count,student.department,student.college_id from student group by department)T1
inner join (select count(*)as fact_count,faculty_per.department,faculty_per.college_id from faculty_per group by department)T2
on T1.college_id=T2.college_id);    i tried this..its running but not showing the desired output

Comment: update the question with desired output and output you are getting in a tabular form